# Textbook recommendation on hyperbolic functions including practice problems

Tags: calculus, functions, book-recommendation

I tried to find e-book in this topic, but mostly e-book only mentions definition some identities and about calculus, but it's so short; not over 20 pages and no practice problems.

Can anyone recommend a book about this topic?

Comment: Did you mean hyperbolic functions? Can you provide the title of the e-book you are using?

Comment: um,may be I used wrong word. Mostly It's note,Lecture,or some subsection in calculus book

Comment: yes,I mean hyperbolic function

Comment: Do these help? http://math.furman.edu/~dcs/book/c6pdf/sec67.pdf, https://www.saylor.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/HYPERBOLIC-FUNCTIONS.pdf, http://www.cimt.org.uk/projects/mepres/alevel/fpure_ch2.pdf, https://www.deanza.edu/faculty/kleincharles/pdf/HyperbolicFunctionsProblems.pdf, http://www.personal.soton.ac.uk/jav/soton/HELM/workbooks/workbook_6/6_2_hyperbolic_fn.pdf, http://douis.net/css/alevel/fp_2/hyperbolic_EQ_fp2.pdf

Comment: @Moo Thank for link  ^  ^